# How to monitor apps which are being executed by user

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I want to create an application/service to monitor user activity, especially to log every application that user is running.
Is this possible in c#? I think not. So how to do this in c++ and winapi?
I don't want whole solution because it's surely complicated. Give me an advice only.
Thanks!

Comment: Aren't there lots of such tools already?

Comment: I think Xperf should do what you want to do.

Comment: Of course, there's many tools which are able to do this, but I want to include this funcionality to my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a DLL that hooks CreateProcessW. In this hook, you would (a) do what you want to do when a process is spawned, and (b) inject itself into the new process.

Then, inject the DLL into all currently running processes.

**EDIT:** My [answer to another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033356/is-it-possible-to-hook-the-creation-of-windows-globally-so-i-can-control-where-th/7033419#7033419) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx

This will give you all processes running on the local computer.

To get processes that have a window do:

```
var procWithWindow = from proc in Process.GetProcesses()
                     where IntPtr.Zero != proc.MainWindowHandle
                     select proc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Management.ManagementObjectSearcher Processes = new Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
foreach (Management.ManagementObject Process in Processes.Get())
{
    if (Process.Item("ExecutablePath") != null)
    {
        string ExecutablePath = Process.Item("ExecutablePath").ToString();
        string[] OwnerInfo = new string[2];
        Process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", (object[])OwnerInfo);
        // do something
    }
}
```

The process owner will be available in the `OwnerInfo` string array.

Comment: You're missing () parantheses after ToString [in the if] and Processes.Get [in the foreach]

Comment: you're very welcome. But uhm... You're still missing the () after Processes.Get

Comment: I'm not sure but Your code gets all currently running processes ,right? Instead I want to monitor and catch every process/program exactly when it's starting (i.e. like anti-virus is doing this) to log date and time of execution.

Comment: @daftu, to do that (efficiently), you'd be hooking something like the WinAPI `CreateProcess()`, which is quite troublesome. IT's easier to do a diff between results. Alternatively, you could add your DLL into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\KERNEL`, and it will be loaded whenever a process starts. Use this to determine when a process starts, who its owned by, and talk with a parent service via. IPC.

Comment: @freedompeace, diff between results could be inaccurate, ie. when user execute a program which will be active only for a few seconds and my app will not be able to notice this.  Adding DLL into registry should be a better way, so I'm starting to solve this. Thank You!

Comment: I think I've found the solution: http://code.google.com/p/easyhook-continuing-detours/